# When using Laravel factories how do I ensure two columns are related?

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I have the following factory:

```
class JobFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            "title" => fake()->sentence(),
            "company_id" => Company::factory(),
            "contact_id" => Contact::factory(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Each Contact belongs to a Company, so ideally I'd like the `jobs.company_id` field to match the `contacts.company_id`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: do you really need the `company_id` column in the jobs table in this case? You can always infer it from the related contact.

Comment: It would make filtering jobs by company easier as I won't need to join contacts first, and it allows for contact_id to be optional

Answer (score 0):

You can use the factory methods for relationships.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-factories#belongs-to-relationships

```php
class JobFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition(): array
    {
        $company = Company::factory();
        $contact = Contact::factory()->for($company, 'company');

        return [
            "title" => fake()->sentence(),
            "company_id" => $company,
            "contact_id" => $contact,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It creates a company, adds it to the job, then creates a new company, adds the contact to that company, and then adds this contact to the job.